# R notebook: Rmd and html do not match

Tags: r, rnotebook

I have a .Rmd

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
dplyr::glimpse(cars)
```
````

When I execute the chunk, I get the expected output:
[image: picture of editor output]

However when previewing the notebook I see artifacts:

[image: preview of notebook]

What is going on here? I restarted R, and cleared knitr cache but no luck.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-conda-linux-gnu      
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is only a partial answer (and too long a comment) but it can address at least some confusion.

1.) The problem you have is not new; rather, it is well-known. See the (unanswered) questions [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/previewing-a-tibble-in-an-r-notebook/36752/2) and [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-03/msg00338.html). Also, it does not depend on your specific R session but rather seems to be a general HTML/knitr problem that needs to be fixed. Also, if you google your spurious ASCII color codes there A LOT of Rmd and knitr files popping up with people having the exact same problem, even on CRAN or RStudio pages! ([Exhibit A](https://colorado.rstudio.com/rsc/churn/modeling/tensorflow-w-r.nb.html))

2.) What you see, are ASCII color codes that are due to the grey `<dbl>` text and the otherwise white text output. More specifically, they stem from the 256-color extended color set that has the general form `\u001b[38;5;${ID}m` (Source: second link above).

Sadly, I don't know exactly how to solve the issue but you can at least circumvent it by using only Base R functions that do not change the color scheme within the output! If I come up with a full-fledged answer, I will edit this partial one accordingly.